# Using Multiple AND condition in where clause

Tags: sql, database

I have a table called `Manuscript`

```
BOOKID  AUTHORID BOOKNAME       GENRE   NOOFCOPIES  AMOUNT
B105    A102     Diagnosis      Journal 500         10000
B102    A102     The Essence... Fiction 110         11000
B106    A102     Clinical Sci.  Educat. 125         18750
B104    A103     Mind Games     Fiction 200         20000
B100    A102     Sublime        Fiction 100         10000
B101    A105     C Programming  Educati 125         18750
B103    A101     Scribe         Journal 500         10000
B107    A101     Clinical Chem. Educat. 125         54646
B108    A103     Clinical Chem. Educat. 125         54646
```

How can I get the AuthorId who has published book in all Genre ? Expected output `A102`

Comment: When you post code or anything tabular, it's recommended that you hit the `{}` button so that we can see the formatting. I've tried to clean it up for you (also, there's a preview window below the question box so you can see what your question will look like)

Comment: And don't use tab, use spaces instead (or tell your IDE to use spaces instead of tabs).

Comment: But I am getting "No Data Found Error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute-force approach could be something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT AUTHORID
FROM Manuscript
WHERE AUTHORID IN 
  (SELECT AUTHORID FROM Manuscript WHERE GENRE LIKE 'Journal')
AND AUTHORID IN
  (SELECT AUTHORID FROM Manuscript WHERE GENRE LIKE 'Fiction')
AND AUTHORID IN
  (SELECT AUTHORID FROM Manuscript WHERE GENRE LIKE 'Education')
```

Comment: Nice but you don't need the `DISTINCT` in the subqueries. You need it in the main query.

Comment: But I am getting "No Data Found Error"

Comment: +1 - But this query will need to be changed everytime a new genre is added as that genre needs to be hardcoded.

Answer (score 3):

A generic query which will work even if more genres are added,

```
select "AUTHORID"
  from table1
 group by "AUTHORID"
having count(distinct "GENRE") = (select count(distinct "GENRE") from table1)
```

[**SQLFIDDLE link to above query**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1b01/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

a possible solution would be to get a count of the differnt genres, and then filter based on that:

```
select 
  authorid, count(distinct genre)
from 
  Manuscript
group by 
  authorid
having 
  count(distinct genre) = (select count(distinct genre) from Manuscript)
```